# activity calling is missing

Tags: android, android-intent

i have two sub activities apart from main activity.

The sequence of calls go like this.

Main --> Sub_Activity1 ,then Sub_Activity1 returns to Main Activity.
Main ---> Sub_Activity2, then Sub_Activity2 returns to Main Activity.

But it is not happening. As far i can see only the 2nd sub activity is getting called, it is skipping the first one . but when i disable/comment out  one of the sub activities the other one is working well. but when i want to call one after another it is calling only the second one. where am i going wrong. here is my code

Main Activity:

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    txt.setText("hello world");
    in1= new Intent(TestActivity.this,Number.class);
    //startActivity(in1);
    startActivityForResult(in1, MY_DATA_CHECKCODE);


    in2= new Intent(TestActivity.this,Message.class);
    //startActivity(in1);
    startActivityForResult(in2, MY_DATA_CHECKCODE1);

}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECKCODE) {


        num= data.getStringExtra("number");
        if(num!=null)
        txt.setText(num);

    }

    else if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECKCODE1) {


        num= data.getStringExtra("number");
        if(num!=null)
        txt.setText(num);

    }

}
```

subactivity1 and subactivity2 codes are same which are used to add some string data to a new intent which can be retrieved in the main intent.

```
                     number = et.getText().toString().trim();

            in= new Intent();

            //in.putExtras(b);
            in.putExtra("number", number);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,in);
```

i have changed the variables to use different request codes as well. they are MY_DATA_CHECKCODE and MY_DATA_CHECKCODE1.is there anything wrong in handling the return values in onActivitResult function.please give me ur suggestions to fix this problem. i have googled and but could not find proper solution for it.

Comment: from  here ,http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=302 i have come to know that the activity calling is aynchronous. then how to make the synchronization possible, does anyone know the answer?

Comment: suppose if i want to call  subactivity1 then getsome result, then have to do some operations on it in the main activity and then pass that value to the subactivity2 how will u do it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doc doesn't say what happens if you call startActivityForResult twice.
I think you should put the call to the second activity in the onActivityResult for the first one.

At least this is the way I would do it

Comment: do u mean i need to put the call to second activity in the  if(requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECKCODE){...} bloack?

Comment: then what is the purpose of using the request code, i think it is used to differentiate between which activity is called from the main activity? even if i use ur approach the  first activity is called then second activity is getting called again and again.i think the problem is with the onActivityResult function.

Comment: the purpose of the request code is that the same activity in different moments can start different activities and then it can handle the result from the same method. I did it sometimes. I don't see why your second activity is called several times. It will be called only when the first activity returns.

Comment: probably it is  my mistake,i have set both the MY_DATA_CHECKCODE and MY_DATA_CHECKCODE1 to 0. but now i have changed my way of handling entirely. it is working, but i still have a doubt. suppose if i want to call one subactivity then getsome result, then have to do some operations on it in the main activity and then pass that value to the second sub activity how will u do it??

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood because I have the impression that your solution with two different values for the check_code should work. You start the first activity with startActivityForResult then in onActivityResult you get the result checking that it is from the first. In that case you handle it making your calculation and then you start the second activity waiting for the result with another code.

Comment: Of course I'm assuming that you start new activity because you need to interact with the user to perform the two separated steps...

Comment: Thanks for ur anwer, can u please answer this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598673/how-to-block-current-activity-till-the-tts-engine-is-not-initialized