# how to block current activity till the TTS Engine is not initialized

Tags: android

i have developed an application which has to use TTS Engine.

Now the problem is i need to wait till the  TTS engine is initialized,though  i am using sleep method it is not working well.

here is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ......

    Intent checkin = new Intent();
    checkin.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkin, MY_DATA_CHECKCODE1);
    //l.setOnTouchListener(this);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     tts.speak("Enter sms", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECKCODE) {

if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {

// success, create the TTS instance

tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

tts.setSpeechRate((float) 0.4);


        } 
    }

}
```

instead of above  sleep method  i need to wait till the TTS Engine is not
initialized.so how can i write a neat block of code to resume the current activity after
TTS Engine is initialized, instead of doing a hard coding to check in a loop whether TTS
has been initialized.(i even dont know how to do this as well).

The application is running in to Non-responding state and throwing Null pointer Exception

when I use

```
tts.speak("Enter sms", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

method. So please suggest me the solution to fix this problem. I have googled but could not find any suitable answer.

Comment: Somebody please throw some light on this problem.. i need it  as soon as possible

Comment: Dude hiral, if u see this problem. please respond, now i got the privilege to  chat. i need the solution for this problem urgently..

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask` to start TTS Engine, and you will know it is done when `onPostExecute` is called:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: but i think the TTS engine initialization has to be synchronized,but if TTS Engine is executed as background process the current activity proceeds as it is and returns the Exception.am i correct, please correct me if i am wrong.